# meaning of "putative connection"

Tags: understanding

> This year, the American Association chose as the theme for its annual
>   conference some putative connection to storytelling: "Practices of
>   Historical Narrative.

I am not sure whether I am understanding this sentence correctly. My understanding is:

1. American Association chose a theme for their annual conference.
2. The theme is connected to storytelling.
3. The storytelling mentioned in this sentence is named "Practices of Historical Narrative"

Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Before asking this question, you must have consulted your English language dictionary to learn the meaning of _putative_. Please **[edit]** your question to tell us what you did you not understand about that definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could paraphrase that sentences as follows:

- This year, the American Association chose as the theme for its annual conference "Practices of Historical Narrative," which is allegedly connected with storytelling.

Storytelling refers to narration in general, and historical narrative is generally considered to be connected with it. However, the sentence seems to indicate that the topic is not as specific as would be expected of an association of, I guess, storytellers.

Comment: I would say "reputed to be connected" is a little closer to the mark.

Comment: "Putative" is often, or even very often, used to imply a measure of doubt about the thing that _putative_ modifies.